# mongodb.lock permission denied

Tags: mongodb, archlinux

Using MongoDb on Arch Linux 64bit.  Brand new install.  Trying as root:

```
/etc/rc.d/mongodb start
```

Log says:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 versionCmpTest passed
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 versionArrayTest passed
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 shardObjTest passed
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 shardKeyTest passed
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 isInRangeTest passed
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=580 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=(none)
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.3, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] build info: Linux brynhild.archlinux.org 3.2.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 14 09:11:26 CET 2012 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/data/db", fork: true, journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", port: 27017, rest: "true", vvvv: "true" }
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] User Assertion: 10309:Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 dbexit: 
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Mar 15 12:00:18 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Directory and file persmissions:

```
[root@(none) ~]# ls -lisa /data/db/
total 12
262711 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 15 11:43 .
262710 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 15 11:25 ..
262714 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 15 11:43 journal
261775 0 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 15 11:43 mongod.lock
```

MongoDB conf:

```
port = 27017
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend = true
vvvv = true
journal = true
rest = true
```

I can start a MongoDB instance by `mongod`, but not in the background as above.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I verified /etc/rc.d/mongodb, and I think it will use mongodb user to run the service:

```
[ -z "$PID" ] && /bin/su mongodb -c "/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --fork" > /dev/null
```

I think this error may caused by run mongod using root, so the owner of the mongod.lock is changed to root.

Comment: Doh!  I've done this before.  You're right.. `chown mongodb:users /data` fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I can start a MongoDB instance by mongod, but not in the background as above

When you start `mongod` this way are you actually starting it with all of the same parameters? The lock file is only for that specific folder.

Things to check:

1. Is there already an instance of `mongod` running (`ps -ef | grep mongod`)?
2. Is there something else running on that port?
3. Are you configs correct? Why do you have the `--journal` command, shouldn't this be `--nojournal` [in v2.0+](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters) or simply nothing?

Comment: thanks for the additional info re --journal.  I'll check that out.